# Create DOM filter on Ionic / Angular ion-card

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Ionic project has an ion-card and it is working normally, problem is that the list is growing and I need to set up a field to filter a search, is there any native way in ionic to do this? Or I have to use JQuery for example.

Anyone have a example?

[image]

Card is created dinamically

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let data of dataArray" id="{{ data._id }}">
     <ion-card-content class="p-0">
         <ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-title>
              {{ data.title }}
            </ion-card-title>
            <ion-card-subtitle *ngIf="data.protocol" id="{{data.protocol}}">
                {{ data.protocol }}
            <ion-icon name="copy-outline" (click)="copyProtocol(data.protocol)" class="ml-2"></ion-icon>
          </ion-card-subtitle>
          <ion-card-subtitle>
            {{ data.description }}
          </ion-card-subtitle>
          </ion-card-header>

          <ion-item lines="none" class="ion-float-left">
             {{ data.updatedAt | localDatetime }}
          </ion-item>

         <ion-item lines="none" class="ion-float-right">
         <ion-tab-button (click)="menu(data._id, data.title, data.description, data.visibility)">
         <ion-icon name="ellipsis-vertical-outline"></ion-icon>
         </ion-tab-button>
        </ion-item>

     <ion-item lines="none" *ngIf="data.marking" class="w-100">
     <ion-label class="w-100" *ngIf="data.marking">{{ data.marking }}</ion-label>
     </ion-item>
</ion-card-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a filter using JQuery, basic filter, maybe someonte can help to improve :-)

But this search is case sensitive, how to solve it?

```
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="filterChannel($event.target.value)"></ion-searchbar>
```

JQuery code

```
 filterChannel(search: any) {
    $("ion-card-title").each(function () {
      if ($(this).text().indexOf(search) != -1) {
        $(this).closest("ion-card").removeClass('d-none');
      }
      else {
        $(this).closest("ion-card").addClass('d-none');
      }
    });
  }
```